# Get the size of a google bucket in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, bucket, gsutil

Is there any way i can get the size of a bucket from the google cloud in java.

I know you can get it like this:

`gsutil du -s gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/`

Is it possible to somehow obtain the total size of a bucket thorugh the java API?

Answer (score 1):

There is no function to get the size of a bucket with java API [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/snippets/StorageSnippets.java).

You can iterate over blobs in the bucket and calculate the total size using `blob.getSize()` but it would be very slow.

According to the official documentation, `gsutil du` can take a long time for large buckets [Getting bucket information](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-bucket-information#bucket-size):

> Caution: The gsutil du command calculates space usage by making object
>   listing requests, which can take a long time for large buckets. If the
>   number of objects in your bucket is hundreds of thousands or more, use
>   Stackdriver instead

An alternative solution would be to enable the bucket logging and check the size of the bucket from the logs:

[Setting up log delivery](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#delivery)

[Carefully calculating Google Cloud Storage Buckets size with Cloud Functions & Pub/Sub](https://blog.doit-intl.com/carefully-calculating-google-cloud-storage-buckets-size-with-cloud-functions-pub-sub-89ac34676629)

Here you can find a related question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374138/fastest-way-to-get-google-storage-bucket-size).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I actually need to delete buckets via a job which i implemented in java spring. But the api can not delete buckets that are not empty.